# Want to add regional info on top of an existing Google Map interacting with the user's touch

Tags: c#, android, google-maps

I have a mobile app that uses the Android GoogleMap Api to display a route on the GoogleMap and then I add markers along the route. I have the user define the route using start/end/viapoints. I would really like to have my app let the user define a route using the GoogleMaps app user interface instead and then let my app get the resulting polyline so I can display the route and add unique markers along the route. Essentially I am trying not to recreate the awesome way the GoogleMap app user interface has the user define the route with all of the possible route options. Is there an api to display the GoogleMap user interface to define a route and allow my app get the resulting polyline data?

I am new to Android development. I have not described my request clearly. The app I have created currently works. It prompts the user for the route start/end/viapoints. It then converts the route start/end/viapoints (street, city, state, zip code) to GPS positions using a geocoder. It then makes a HTTP request ("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/...") and it then deserializes the JSON response to get the route OverviewPolyline.Points and saves them. It will use this information to display the route using a Google Map Control. I add Markers to display additional info along the route displayed by the map control. I only use the route information so I can add my extended information using Markers along the route.
If there was a way I could use the built in maps app (i.e. "http://maps.google.com/?daddr=San+Francisco,+CA&saddr=Mountain+View") to let the user define the route and then I get the route polyline info from that.

Even better would be to design the app to add the ability to add these markers on to the existing google map. I only want to provide distinctly different information on top of what Google Maps provides. I want to let the user indicate by touch of the map where to display this timely regional info. I want to allow the user to also turn the display of this info (Markers/BillBoards) on or off, to show todays info, tomorrow's info, the next days, etc. This information is most useful over a longer route where the time to travel is more than an hour, perhaps days. So what APIs are available to add functionality on top of the Google Map without having to provide a duplicate of what Google Maps already does?

Comment: Can you share some of the relevant code that you've already tried? What are the desired results and how does that differ from what's actually happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some code snippits that might help you.  I haven't done the part where I record the position of a point on the map that a user clicks on, but that should be relatively easy.  This mainly explains saving and drawing the polyline information.

```
    // Some imports
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;
...
// Declare the pathDynamic
private PolylineOptions pathDynamic;
...
pathDynamic = new PolylineOptions().width(15).color(Color.RED);
...
// Whenever the user clicks the map to add a point
LatLng theLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());         
pathDynamic.add(theLatLng);
...
// Add the polyline to the map
if (mMap != null) {
    mMap.addPolyline(pathDynamic);
}
...
//If you want to save the points to an encoded string to store in a database
String encoded_path = encode(pathDynamic.getPoints());
...
//If you want to put an encoded_path into a pathDynamic
pathDynamic = new PolylineOptions().width(15).color(Color.RED);
pathDynamic.addAll(decode(encoded_path));
...
    /**
 * Decodes an encoded path string into a sequence of LatLngs.
 */
public static List<LatLng> decode(final String encodedPath) {
    int len = encodedPath.length();

    // For speed we preallocate to an upper bound on the final length, then
    // truncate the array before returning.
    final List<LatLng> path = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    int index = 0;
    int lat = 0;
    int lng = 0;

    while (index < len) {
        int result = 1;
        int shift = 0;
        int b;
        do {
            b = encodedPath.charAt(index++) - 63 - 1;
            result += b << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x1f);
        lat += (result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1);

        result = 1;
        shift = 0;
        do {
            b = encodedPath.charAt(index++) - 63 - 1;
            result += b << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x1f);
        lng += (result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1);

        path.add(new LatLng(lat * 1e-5, lng * 1e-5));
    }

    return path;
}

/**
 * Encodes a sequence of LatLngs into an encoded path string.
 */
public static String encode(final List<LatLng> path) {
    long lastLat = 0;
    long lastLng = 0;

    final StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

    for (final LatLng point : path) {
        long lat = Math.round(point.latitude * 1e5);
        long lng = Math.round(point.longitude * 1e5);

        long dLat = lat - lastLat;
        long dLng = lng - lastLng;

        encode(dLat, result);
        encode(dLng, result);

        lastLat = lat;
        lastLng = lng;
    }
    return result.toString();
}

private static void encode(long v, StringBuffer result) {
    v = v < 0 ? ~(v << 1) : v << 1;
    while (v >= 0x20) {
        result.append(Character.toChars((int) ((0x20 | (v & 0x1f)) + 63)));
        v >>= 5;
    }
    result.append(Character.toChars((int) (v + 63)));
}
```